# HTML form ignores file section

Tags: python, html, flask

When I submit my form, by analyzing request I saw that every field is submitted except file data and I don't know why. I would really be happy if anybody could give me a hint how to solve this problem.

my route.py file

```
@users.route("/account",  methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def account():
    form = UpdateAccountForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.pic.data:
            file_data = save_pict(form.pic.data)
            current_user.picture = file_data
        else:
            print("no data was sent")    
        current_user.username = form.username.data
        current_user.email = form.email.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Your profile was updated!", "success")

        return redirect(url_for("users.account"))
```

forms file

```
class UpdateAccountForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField("Username", validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=5, max=15)])
    email = StringField("Email", validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    pic = FileField("Update Picture", validators=[FileAllowed(["jpeg", "png"])])
    submit = SubmitField("Update")
```

HTML file

```
    <div class="content-section">
        <div class="media">
            <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src={{image}}>
            <br>
            <div class="media-body">
                <br>
                <h2 class="account-heading">{{current_user.username}}</h2>
                <p class="secondary">{{current_user.email}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="registration-form">
            <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {{form.hidden_tag()}}
                <fieldset class="form-group"><br>
                    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Account info</legend>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{form.username.label(class="form-control-label")}}

                        {%if form.username.errors%}
                            {{form.username(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid")}}
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {%for error in form.username.errors%}
                                    <span>{{error}}</span>
                                {%endfor%}
                            </div>
                        {%else%}
                            {{form.username(class="form-control form-control-lg")}}
                        {%endif%}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{form.email.label(class="form-control-label")}}

                        {%if form.email.errors%}
                            {{form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid")}}
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {%for error in form.email.errors%}
                                    <span>{{error}}</span>
                                {%endfor%}
                            </div>
                        {%else%}
                            {{form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg")}}
                        {%endif%}
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form.pic.label() }}
                        {{ form.pic(class="form-control-file") }}
                        {% if form.pic.errors %}
                            {% for error in form.pic.errors %}
                                <span class="text-danger">{{ error }}</span></br>
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>

                </fieldset>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info")}}
                    
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So when I inspect body of the request every field is present except file field, and nothing is submitted to database

[request body photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIiu2.png)

Comment: What is the rendered html ? Specifically for the file input

Comment: <input class="form-control-file" id="pic" name="pic" type="file">. this is how rendered version looks like if I understood what you asking